# Postgresql-Ocaml Bindings and Errors

Tags: ocaml

This following piece of code works when the database is already created, but fails if the database is not created. The more concerning issue for me is that my code is *not* catching the error thrown by the code when the database has not been created. I am new to Ocaml error handling, so I am wondering why this does not work. Here is the error I receive:

```
Fatal error: exception Postgresql.Error(_)
```

and here is the code I have:

```
open Postgresql;;

let main () = ( 
  let c = new connection ~host:"localhost" ~port:"5432" ~dbname:"stocks" ~user:"postgres"
    ~password:"postgres" ()  in  
  let status ()  = (   
  try match c#status with 
    | Ok -> print_string ("STATUS CONNECTED\n"); 
    | Bad -> print_string "BAD";
  with Error(s) ->( print_string (string_of_error(s))))  in  
  status();  

  c#finish   
);;

main();;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that exception is raised in `let c  = ....` statement because it is not located inside `try....with` block. Code example below is not ideal but more OCaml-way than you have.

```
 open Postgresql

 let with_connection f =
   try
     let c = new connection ~host:"localhost" ~port:"5432" ~dbname:"stocks" ~user:"postgres"
       ~password:"postgres" () in
     f c;
     c#finish
   with _ -> print_endline "ERROR"

 let main () = 
   with_connection (fun c ->  
     try match c#status with 
       | Ok -> print_string ("STATUS CONNECTED\n"); 
       | Bad -> print_string "BAD";
     with Error(s) ->( print_string (string_of_error(s))))  
    )


 let () = main ()
```

Comment: where should the 'in' keyword go?

Comment: It's difficult question. You can try to get inspiration from my code above.